# Cannot convert from 'object' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game an I have a problem with coding the aiming mechanism and I'm having problem with the "offset".
Here is the error I get:
"error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'object' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'"

```
protected virtual void UpdateHeadTrack()
    {
        if (!shooterManager || !headTrack)
        {
            if (headTrack) headTrack.offsetSpine = Vector2.Lerp(headTrack.offsetSpine, Vector2.zero, headTrack.smooth * Time.deltaTime);
            return;
        }
        if (!CurrentWeapon || !headTrack)
        {
            if (headTrack) headTrack.offsetSpine = Vector2.Lerp(headTrack.offsetSpine, Vector2.zero, headTrack.smooth * Time.deltaTime);
            return;
        }
        if (isAiming || aimTimming > 0f)
        {
            object offset = cc.isCrouching ? CurrentWeapon.headTrackOffsetCrouch : CurrentWeapon.headTrackOffset;
            headTrack.offsetSpine = Vector2.Lerp(headTrack.offsetSpine, offset, headTrack.smooth * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            headTrack.offsetSpine = Vector2.Lerp(headTrack.offsetSpine, Vector2.zero, headTrack.smooth * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use `Vector2 offset = ...`?

Comment: I tried that and I got a new error: `error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) `

Comment: How are `headTrackOffsetCrouch` and `headTrackOffset` declared? They should be `Vector2` as well. You should use `object` only in rare cases where a variable or a parameter must accept a wide range of types.

Comment: They were declared as `objects`, i changed them to `Vector2` and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `offset` as a `Vector2`:

```
Vector2 offset = cc.isCrouching ? CurrentWeapon.headTrackOffsetCrouch : CurrentWeapon.headTrackOffset;
```

And also define `headTrackOffsetCrouch` and `headTrackOffset` as `Vector2`:

```
public Vector2 headTrackOffsetCrouch;

public Vector2 headTrackOffset;
```